# How can I download and install Numpy and Pandapower?

Tags: numpy, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, miniconda, pandapower

How can I Download and install numpy and pandapower on the RASPBIAN JESSIE LITE Minimal image based on Debian Jessie? the one without the GUI. And how can I download and install Pip and miniconda on it as well?

Comment: That's a basic "how do I use Debian's package management" question (hint: don't use Pip for anything that you can directly get through that package management system, `apt-get`). You can find that out by googling for things like "debian getting started".

Comment: You can use apt-get to do it, but this really isn't the place to be asking.

Answer (score -1):

um i am pretty sure the commands are the same are they not? Have you searched this up yet? i am sure that if you have another computer you can just search up miniconda and copy the download link and follow the instructions. pip is automatically installed in miniconda and if you dont have it do

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

and for numpy do

```
pip -U install numpy
```

or

```
conda install numpy
```

for pandapower

```
conda install pandapower
pip -U install pandapower
```

or if you cant get miniconda with the method above just do

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

that will get you python and pip.

Good Luck!!

Comment: No I don't think they are the same, because every time I run the commands (pip -U install numpy / conda install numpy) it tells me command not found(same for pandapower). also when I run (sudo apt-get install python-pip) it tells me E: Unable to locate package python-pip.

Comment: that is because you first have to install python to get pip and if u dont have python or miniconda u cant get numpy and the others

Comment: I do when I run (sudo apt-get install python). it says python is already the newest version. and when i run ( python -V) to check the python version installed it tells me it is (Python 2.7.9). So, yeah I believe I have python installed.

Comment: does it have pip installed?